# Multi-tenant Dependency Resolution with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container, multi-tenant

Consider the interface `IWorkflow`, is a contract in our SDK that we define. A tenant may provide their own custom implementation of `IWorkflow`. So at runtime, we need dynamically load based on the tenant context:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterTenantCustomizations();
var workflow0 = container.ResolveForTenant<IWorkflow>("tenant0");
var workflow1 = container.ResolveForTenant<IWorkflow>("tenant1");
var workflow2 = container.ResolveForTenant<IWorkflow>("tenant2");
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What would this extension method have to look like?
Does Unity IOC provide an attribute that we can use to decorate the class as to their respective tenant?

Comment: Why not have a separate container per tenant, if there is no entry in the tenant specific container, fallback to the default ones, looks simple and neat a'int it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you define the definitions in the composition root as this

```
container.RegisterType<IWorkflow, TenantClassDefault>();
container.RegisterType<IWorkflow, TenantClass0>("tenant0");
container.RegisterType<IWorkflow, TenantClass1>("tenant1");
container.RegisterType<IWorkflow, TenantClass2>("tenant2");
```

Then you can extend the IUnityContainer interface and create your resolver like this

```
public static class IUnityContainerExt
{
    public static IWorkflow ResolveForTenant(this IUnityContainer container, string name)
    {
        IWorkflow workflow;
        try
        {
            workflow = container.Resolve<IWorkflow>(name); 
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException e)
        {
            //If the resolver can't resolve the name it will throw ResolutionFailedException and you can select the default instead
            workflow = container.Resolve<IWorkflow>();
        }
        return workflow;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it directly on the container

```
var workflow0 = container.ResolveForTenant("tenant1");
```

You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660853(v=pandp.20).aspx)

Comment: Interesting, Is there anyway, we could achieve that using a custom attribute? We'd need to support the edge used default is no type is registered for the tenant.